# Shortcut to insert \linebreak{} in lyx

Tags: shortcuts, lyx

I would like to define a shortcut in lyx 2.3.1 (ubuntu 18.04) to insert a `\linebreak{}`, so that the current line is split into two, and I can insert several empty lines this way.

How should I enter this command in lyx shortcuts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu Tools->Preferences->Editing->Shortcuts it is possible to assign a shortcut to the function `newline-insert linebreak`. This will give an ability to insert line breaks and arbitrary number of empty lines in lyx.